# la consola de javascript me devuelve null

Tags: javascript, html, consola

Lo primero de todo es agradecerles a las dos personas que me contestaron por ayudarme, pero he encontrado otra forma de hacerlo, aunque me arroja un pequeño error.
He creado el siguiente código en javascript para que me imprima el valor de ambos input en la consola de mi buscador, pero resulta que en vez de devolverme el valor que debería me devuelve null.
Si me pudieran ayudar con eso ...
Cabe destacar que el código html es el mismo que el de la pregunta anterior

```
var usr = localStorage.getItem("usr");

var psw = localStorage.getItem("psw");
console.log(psw +" "+ psw);
```

Comment: Si tienes creados esos valores en el localstorage?

Comment: Ni idea cuál es la pregunta anterior. Las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas :)

Comment: Parece que no hay ningún dato en localStorage con ese nombre y para esa web.

Comment: En StackOverflow cada pregunta debe entenderse por si sola, ya que el visitante promedio, como yo, no tenemos idea de cuál es tu pregunta anterior. Encontrarás más información en [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: Con los datos que hay, lo que "debería" devolver es justamente `null`